# Change Unanswered tab to Review

Tags: script, navigation

### About

This is ([allegedly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/75572/please-make-review-route-available-as-a-link-somewhere)) going to be implemented by the team sometime anyway. But just in case, and so you can play with it, here is a script which replaces the 'Unanswered' tab with 'Review'. *NEW - attempts to notify user if the script becomes irrelevant (i.e. when this gets implemented by the team).*.

[image: Screenshot]

### Source

If you have Firefox+Greasemonkey, Opera, or Google Chrome, try this Greasemonkey script that will transform the Unanswered tab into a Review tab.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           FutureReview
// @author         benjol
// @version        1.0.1
// @description    Hack Unanswered tab to point to review
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        https://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include        http://meta.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude        http://*.gaming.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude        http://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

function with_jquery(f) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};

with_jquery(function ($) {
    var unanswered = document.getElementById('nav-unanswered');
    if(unanswered == null) 
      notify.show('You can uninstall the <a href="https://stackapps.com/questions/2069/change-unanswered-tab-to-review">FutureReview</a> script, the functionality seems to now be built in to Stack Exchange', -123456);
    unanswered.innerHTML = 'Review';
    unanswered.href = '/review';
    if(location.pathname.indexOf('/review') > -1) {
        unanswered.parentNode.className += ' youarehere';
    }
});
```

### Installation

Save the above to disk as "futurereview.user.js" and drag it into your browser—or simply [go here for a direct download of the above file](https://gist.github.com/raw/833494/74ebad5646db286ed4910eb8a3048de13f7fcc83/futurereview.user.js).

For more information about user scripts, check out [the](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) [script](/questions/tagged/script)   [tag wiki](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).

### Note

Disabled on [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com): the tabs texts are image-based there.

You can use my [other user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments-for-review-educating-users-before-flagging) for commenting on the low-quality posts you find in Review.

Comment: This script is now irrelevant.