# Stack Exchange Side-By-Side Edit and Preview

Tags: script, editing

> **Note:** the new inline editing breaks this user script pretty seriously, so it doesn't work at the moment. I will be working on fixing it to work with the new system when I get a chance, but it may take a while before I can do that.

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: stack exchange side-by-side]

### About

In response to [requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/72645/could-the-change-from-an-edit-be-displayed-in-a-side-by-side-display) for an option to show the markdown preview next to the text editor, and my own desire for this feature, I have created a small user script to do this. The **Stack Exchange Side-By-Side Editor** (SE-SBS) adds a link to your edit toolbar to enter side-by-side editing mode.

[image: sbs launch]

This mode creates a lightboxed window with just the edit text area and the markdown preview. In Chrome, the edit area will resize dynamically with the window to best fit the size. The markdown preview will always be the default width, so that your preview looks exactly how it will on the page.

This script is also designed to play nicely with the [SE Editor Toolkit](https://stackapps.com/questions/2209/se-editor-toolkit). When the editor toolkit is detected, the link is shortened to allow space for the toolkit's buttons. The editor toolkit is disabled in side-by-side mode, but gets re-enabled when you return to normal editing mode.

[image]

#### Download

Download the script [here](http://nathanhinkle.com/software/se-sbs/), then follow the [instructions](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) on the Stack Apps [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag-wiki.

- [Direct link to user script](http://files.nathanhinkle.com/download/se-sbs.user.js)

#### Platform

Works for asking a question, editing an existing question or answer, and adding a new answer.

Tested on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, Web Apps, Gaming, Ask Ubuntu, OnStartups, and several other SE 2.0 sites.

Tested in Firefox 4 w/ Greasemonkey and Chrome 10.

#### License

This script is released under a [Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/) license. Basically, you're free to change and redistribute it for non-commercial purposes if you credit the author (myself).

### Known problems:

- Edit text area does not automatically resize in Firefox. This is due to how `position:fixed` is handled in Firefox differently from in Chrome. A workaround is in progress.
- Markdown preview automatically scrolls back to the top whenever the preview is refreshed. Still under investigation.
- Broken on Ask Different, due to the very different styling and copious use of `!important` in the site's stylesheet. Under investigation.

### Contact

The best way to provide feedback on this script is by adding answers or comments below. You can also contact me at the email address listed in my Stack Exchange profile.

Comment: Bug report: this doesn't work correctly on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @GeorgeEdison thanks for the tip. It looks like Ask Different's stylesheet is substantially different from most SE sites. I'll take a look at this soon.

Comment: Nice, if your screen is large enough. Bug: I can't see the edit summary in side-by-side mode (Chrome 11.0.696.48). I can return to normal mode to fill it in, but that makes it more likely that I'll forget to enter a summary. Feature request: being able to see the question (with scrolling).

Comment: This is freaking awesome! :-)

Comment: @nhinkle Is it possible to restore the page to the position I was reading when clicking on "Exit side-by-side edit mode" instead of bringing the scroll bar to the begining of the page :?

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. It'll be a few weeks until I can work on this more (it's exam time), but I will take all of your suggestions into consideration for the next version and see what I can do.

Comment: bug report [Inline editing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/53916/inline-editing-for-stack-exchange-sites) breaks Side-by-side

Comment: I will look into this; thanks for the info @Sathya.

Comment: Now that is a feature I would like to have. Is there any chance for an update soon?

Comment: @Raphael I haven't had time to look at this recently, but will try to poke around a bit and see if I can get it working again.

Comment: Can you add this to the Chrome Web Store and have Google review it as non-malicious? Then put an "inline install" link here. Google recently changed how Chrome extensions (including user-scripts) are installed - a user has to manually install any unverified third-party extensions. In other words, SE users have to go to Tools > Extensions and drag-drop the downloaded JS file. More info: http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664769&p=crx_warning

Comment: The Chrome Web Store suggestion is for when (if?) you fix this. Also, please get rid of the super-thick black border and use that extra space to widen/lengthen the editor/preview. You could also just have a simple `X` at the top right corner to go back to the normal view.

Comment: Does this still work - Chrome 44? 
Is this still the best way? Are there any other ways to make Edit and Preview be visible side by side?

Comment: @AlexS I haven't updated this in years, and I don't think it still works. Sorry.

Comment: @nhinkle I have tried and it seem to work, but only issue is it works for new posts, not while editing existing ones. The problem can be easily cracked I guess. While trying to edit existing posts, the side preview appears, but left editor pane is just not editable. if you could fix that, its still best way to use. Please consider.

Comment: Hello, I came from this  -> https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29941/firefox-plugin-to-show-edit-and-preview-panels-side-by-side (I am the OP). According to the last commenter in the above, this tool may still work. But I can't find the file download here. Could you help? Thanks.