# Stack Exchange Post Editor - Performing Basic Corrections on Posts Automatically

Tags: script

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

This script was originally inspired by [SE Editor Toolkit](https://stackapps.com/q/2209). Unfortunately, the toolkit is packaged as a Safari extension and as such is unusable in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. I had written a PHP script that converted the Safari extension to a UserScript but it didn't work very well and was completely broken on Firefox.

Hence this script was born. It is an attempt to write, from the ground up, a script that performs automatic correction of common misspellings and removes unnecessary "thank you"s in the post (and title). The script also provides a live diff viewer that allows you to see what changes have been made to the post.

Everything I've described above is currently implemented to a usable degree, but there is still a *lot* more work to be done - so if you are interested, fork the code and help contribute!

#### License

Stack Exchange Post Editor is released under the [GNU General Public License (GPL) 3](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0)

#### Download

You can download Stack Exchange Post Editor here:
https://github.com/nathan-osman/Stack-Exchange-Post-Editor/raw/master/sepostedit.user.js

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

Stack Exchange Post Editor is written in JavaScript and jQuery.

The code can be retrieved from here:
https://github.com/nathan-osman/Stack-Exchange-Post-Editor

Comment: Does it autocapitalize, insert apostrophes etc? If so, how is that done through the tool (to be honest, I have clicked the button, but nothing has happened)

Comment: @soandos: It currently corrects a few common misspellings ('teh' => 'the') and ALL CAPS. There are a lot of other features that are planned but not implemented yet.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Chrome 30.0.1599.114 running on Debian. I tried with a question of mine that I I edited to contain `teh`, Ctrl_clicked the edit link so as not to use the inline editor and nothing happened. Do I need to do something to activate it? I see that   soandos mentions a button, I take it I should be seeing a new button somewhere then?

Comment: Seems broken on Firefox too.

Comment: If someone would like to take over this project, I would be willing to transfer ownership of the repository.

Comment: The link to the download is broken

Comment: For future reference: The userscript isn't directly installable any more. You'll need to compile it manually first.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a list of contractions without the apostrophe and what they should be corrected to:

- arent aren't
- cant  can't
- couldnt   couldn't
- didnt didn't
- doesnt    doesn't
- dont  don't
- hadnt hadn't
- hasnt hasn't
- havent    haven't
- hed   he'd
- hes   he's
- Id    I'd
- Im    I am
- Ive   I've
- isnt  isn't
- mightnt   mightn't
- mustnt    mustn't
- shant shan't
- shes  she's
- shouldnt  shouldn't
- thats that's
- theres    there's
- theyd they'd
- theyll    they'll
- theyre    they're
- theyve    they've
- weve  we've
- werent    weren't
- whatll    what'll
- whatre    what're
- whats what's
- whatve    what've
- wheres    where is
- whod  who'd
- wholl who'll
- whove who've
- wont  won't
- wouldnt   wouldn't
- youd  you'd
- youll you'll
- youre you're
- youve you've