# Stack Exchange Editor Toolkit

Tags: script, editing

[image: Stack Exchange Editor Toolkit Logo]

This userscript is a revival of sorts for the old [SE Editor Toolkit](https://stackapps.com/questions/2209/se-editor-toolkit), which was abandoned some time ago.

It only really provides the autocorrect aspect for the foreseeable future, which I find to be quite useful.

It works by injecting a button in the edit window (it works inline for users with full edit privileges and on edit pages for users without them) that corrects common errors based on current Stack Exchange standards and formulates an edit summary based on the changes.

## Usage

[image: Usage]

<sub>[Bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpBaj.gif)</sub>

## Rules

It currently does the following:

- Uppercases lowercase "i"s in posts
- Corrects to proper spelling/capitalization of "Stack Overflow" and "Stack Exchange" in order to fit the legal naming requirements
- Expands "SO" and "SE" to "Stack Overflow" and "Stack Exchange," respectively
- Corrects to proper spelling/capitalization of...

  - JavaScript
  - JSFiddle
  - jQuery
  - HTML
  - CSS
  - JSON
  - AJAX
  - AngularJS
  - PHP
  - Android
  - Oracle
  - SQL/SQLite
  - Windows
  - Upvote/Downvote
- Capitalizes the first letter of new lines
- Removes common greetings
- Removes "thanks" and similar phrases
- Removes "Edit:" and similar modifiers
- Replaces the now-banned mysite.domain with example.domain
- Fixes improperly used contractions

## Expandability

See something you don't like? Want to add something?

Well, the toolkit is easily expanded/modified. Rules are in the following format (located in the `edits` dictionary):

```
anArbitraryName: {
        expr: /aRegularExpressionForMatching/,
        replacement: "What to replace it with (may include captured text like $1)",
        reason: "an unpunctuated reason starting with a lowercase letter that will be formatted automatically and inserted into the edit summary"
},
```

## Download

Click [here](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit/raw/master/editor.user.js) for a direct download of the current version.

## Contribute

The code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit) (feel free to make pull requests with new rules if you're into that sort of thing).

Please post reports of bugs/strange behavior on the GitHub page [as an issue](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit/issues) or here as an answer or comment.

## A Note of Warning

One last thing: as this script is entirely based on loosely-constructed regular expressions, it may have unexpected behavior. While I haven't encountered anything too terrible, kindly understand that I am not responsible for any damage caused to posts by its usage and ***always* make sure to check what the script did before (or right after) you submit your edits**.

If you are edit-banned for something this script did, please remember this warning.

(You will be automatically reminded once on each new site you visit where you do not have edit privileges that your edits must pass through a queue and that the script may not fix enough of a post to be accepted.)

Comment: I'm having a small problem. The button doesn't actually show up until I click the orange question mark on the right two times...

Comment: @AlexK That's odd; it should show up immediately. Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Something weird is going on here...when I have the console open, it works perfectly. Without the console, when I load the page, about half the times the image doesn't show up...

Comment: Yup. I just tried this again. What I said is confirmed...which is really weird. What's going on?

Comment: @AlexK That's odd; you may want to open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @AlexK I think my bug report might be similar to what you're experiencing https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit/issues/36

Comment: @Sathya awesome - soit should be fixed now?

Comment: @AlexK yes, it should. Fetch the latest version, do try it.

Comment: *Removes "Edit:" and similar modifiers* I think the *Edit:* text can be useful, even if I don't have an example right now. But it highlights the fact that the OP has taken time to improve his question, so I think it's interesting.

Comment: @A.L It can sometimes be useful, but it's generally frowned upon. If you'd like to disable it, you can remove the `edit` rule from the `App.edits` dictionary.

Comment: Found an issue: It turns "i.e:" into "I.e:" where it shouldn't. Consider adding this case?

Comment: @AJFarmar Fixed! Thanks, and sorry it took a year for me to get to that simple fix.

Comment: Usage gifs links are broken now. How can I use that?

Comment: Does this still work?