# Autonavigate/autocomment "close/flag offtopic" for MSO

Tags: script

On MSO, there are plenty of questions that should be on SO asked every day.

The procedure with dealing with these is:

- Copy-paste boilerplate comment saying "This belongs on SO blah". Alternatively, use [Pro-forma comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se), and navigate the menu
- Navigate the flag menu/close menu to "off topic".

This takes quite a few clicks and is annoying; especially since you're dealing with a question that shouldn't be there in the first place.

### Installation

- Click here to install: [Close offtopic](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/CloseOffTopic.user.js)/[Flag offtopic](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/FlagOffTopic.user.js) Will only work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey).
- Source: [Close offtopic](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/CloseOffTopic.user.js)/[Flag offtopic](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/FlagOffTopic.user.js)

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]