# Transmogrify offtopic MSO posts

Tags: script, meta, fun

> See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/134710/178438

Oftentimes, MSO is cluttered with offtopic programming questions asked by those who want to circumvent a question ban. These posts are eyesores, and this script is an attempt to improve them for the duration of their short lifespans.

It auto-navigates the close menu, downvotes the post,  and fills the answer box with a Calvin and Hobbes strip (Community Wiki). It's similar to [this script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3327/autonavigate-autocomment-close-flag-offtopic-for-mso) in the autonavigation.

**Note:**Please check if the image exists. The script sometimes chooses 404 images. (There are gaps in the archive). Hit the transmogrify button again to fetch a new image.

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/TransmogrifyOffTopic.user.js). Will only work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey).  See [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you have trouble.
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/TransmogrifyOffTopic.user.js)

### Usage

Click "transmogrify" button below post. Post answer, and then cast close vote (the "off topic" option is pre selected for your convenience).

Comment: The transmogrify button isn't showing up under the post

Comment: You need to update the script, it doesn't work anymore. First of all, you need to change the site where it works to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/*` (instead of `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/*`). Also, after doing that, I get an error that says "_Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/master/StackExchange/TransmogrifyOffTopic.js?rand=46' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled._" in Chrome. I have no idea what that means, but hopefully you do.

Comment: @user53888 That'll be because the userscript is actually just a wrapper for an externally-hosted script.

Answer (score 10):

This is great. Love it. Thanks man!

Suggestions for additional taglines:

- I'm so glad you asked me that, but I have no clue how to solve it. Have a Calvin & Hobbes strip instead!
- I have no idea. However, legend has it that reading Calvin & Hobbes strips will increase your problem solving ability so maybe that can help you.
- I have no idea. But here's a Calvin & Hobbes strip to help console you.
- This is a great question - I'm completely dumbfounded as to what its solution is. But I *do* have a Calvin & Hobbes strip!
- I'm completely clueless. Please accept this Calvin & Hobbes strip as a gesture of shame and apology.

Comment: Added, uninstall-reinstall to get it. I've made it autoupdate as well, so no need to do that again in the future. Thanks :)

Comment: @Manishearth and Pekka, I just want to say that this is by far my favorite StackApp. I still get a kick out of seeing these posted on off-topic MSO questions. ;)

Comment: @jmort that's nice to hear! Most of the activity stopped in light of the "let's not be rude" discussion, but it was fun while it lasted :)

Comment: @jmort me too :)

Answer (score 8):

Feature request: for us poor sods < 3k rep on meta, could you also show the Transmogrification option next to the `flag` link instead, together with an auto-flagging-as-off-topic action?