# Bring back the Bold!

Tags: script

Our insidious overlords have  [made some numbers on the page thinner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/158762/whats-up-with-the-new-css). This script feeds the numbers a sandwich to get them back to normal size.

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/BringBackBold.user.js). Will work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey). See [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you have trouble, or want to install on Opera/Safari/IE.
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/BringBackBold.user.js)

Comment: Consider inserting a stylesheet instead of using jQuery. With your current script, layout inconsistencies may occur if the page is changed by the live update feature. And, stylesheets can also be used with Stylish.

Comment: @RobW OK, will do when I get time.

Comment: Chrome blocks the installation of addons from unknown sources.

Comment: And oh, it works only in question, not on the question list :<

Comment: Check out my extension, which brings back most of the bold: https://github.com/nhahtdh/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/BringBackBold.user.js

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz See http://stackapps.com/tags/script/infofor installation issues. There's a specific way to install userscripts in certain Chrome versions. I was planning on doing the other fixes later, but `@`nhahtdh fixed it first :)

Comment: Hey Manishearth, what you can do is go into the directory in Chrome where the userscript is installed, and grab both the script AND the manifest file. add in [manifest_version:2](https://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/manifestVersion.html) property to the manifest, then you can ZIP it up and upload it to the Chrome Web Store! Basically, Userscripts are converted to extensions automatically by Chrome, and this would virtually eliminate installation issues. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @jmort253 Oh, I know about extensions, I've written a few for personal use (and I'm writing https://github.com/Manishearth/ChemistryStackSkin currently)... But I'll have to set up the Chrome Web Store account (I plan on doing that later), it seems to be a not-so-simple process.

Comment: It's the $5 fee that's the most complex, but once you get past that, it's a lot less of a hassle. ;)  (And yes, I think I'm using some of your scripts. I was sad to see [transmogrify](http://stackapps.com/questions/3477/transmogrify-offtopic-mso-posts) break ;( )

Comment: @jmort253 Yeah, but as a student, it's a bit harder for me to get the $5 fee done (I'll ask for it when I next get home, no biggie). Exactly what's broken in transmogrify?

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll have to fix it to use another comics provider then :S

Answer (score 2):

To keep the light grey color of the question/answer reputations on question pages, I added the following lines to the top part:

```
        '.question-page .vote-count-post { \
            color: rgb(128, 129, 133); \
        }' +
```