# Link Only Answer Automatic Flagging

Tags: script, flags

> Thank you to Manishearth for giving me the idea here
>
> [Autonavigate/autocomment "close/flag offtopic" for MSO](https://stackapps.com/questions/3327/autonavigate-autocomment-close-flag-offtopic-for-mso)

As a very avid user of the Stack Exchange, I try to make this place the most efficient it can be. One of the tasks involved with this is flagging. In this particular case, it is flagging answers that only contain links. I come across at least 20 of these a day. As a result, I got tired of doing the same process over and over again. So I decided to automate the process

### How to use

Find a ridiculous post that only contains a link

[image]

Click the `Link Only` link right next to the `flag` link

[image: share | edit | flag | Link Only]

It will bring up the flagging UI, and automatically navigate to the "not an answer flag option.

[image]

It will also downvote and leave this comment

> It is great that you are trying to help the asker out. However, leaving an answer with only a link can be harmful in some cases. While your answer is good now, if the link were ever to die, your answer would lose it's value. So it will be helpful if you summarize the content from the article in your answer. See [this](http://goo.gl/wQTjc) question for clarification.

### How to install

You can grab the Greasemonkey script from [this location](https://gist.github.com/burn123/5650628/raw/e14b36eb6f8b6d025c6ef9d87546723f58d275ac/Link+only+Answers.user.js)

Click [here](https://gist.github.com/burn123/5650628/raw/e14b36eb6f8b6d025c6ef9d87546723f58d275ac/Link+only+Answers) to view the source

Comment: It should be VLQ, not NAA.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Why?

Comment: From what I've understood, NAA is for answers that are completely 'not answers'. Like "I have this problem too"... or "Joe's answer doesn't work for me, why not?"

Comment: The capitalisation of "Link Only" in the bar at the bottom hurts.  Seriously though, I'd recommend rewording the comment to make it sound a bit more polite, especially for new users.  Overall though, not bad - makes quick flagging a lot easier!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Noted. I have made the comment more friendly