# User rename script

Tags: script

### Keep tabs on the newest help vampires!

[image: Renamed user]

This script was inspired by my not immediately spotting a help vampire - because of the user32984923874-style default name. It seemed like a good idea at the time.

#### What does it do?

Allow you to display a different name for any given user: in user cards and on comments.

Modified names are displayed with a little tick afterwards (just so you don't forget).

#### How do you use it?

When you mouseover an eligible user card, it will highlight with a black border, you can then click (don't click on an existing link) and a little prompt will ask you for a different name. You can reclick any time to change the name, and emptying the 'new' field will reset to the original name.

#### What are the hidden features and/or limitations?

- A mini hidden feature is that if the script detects that the user has done the honourable thing and created a real name, your renamed version will be displayed with a cross (instead of a tick).
- However, in this case if you do choose to 'reset', you'll have to refresh the page in order to see the new name
- It won't replace *inside* comments, nor does it attempt to replace on the user's page.
- Currently only applies to Stack Overflow and Meta, but the renames won't be shared between them.
- Another 'side-effect' feature is that you can define a 'rename' where the name is the same: which means you won't be tripped up by meta-users-of-ever-changing-name.

### Installation

Click [HERE](https://gist.github.com/raw/4161013/RenameUser.user.js) to install the user script.

Click [HERE](https://gist.github.com/4161013) to preview the code.

#### Shameless plug

Checkout my [other script](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/876).