# QuickComment2: Automatic keyboard-only comment snippets

Tags: script, comments

This is a vastly improved version of [QuickComment: comment shortcuts to cut down on tedium](https://stackapps.com/q/4796/17430). See that post for more information.

See [the Github repo](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/stackexchange-quickcomment2) for instructions on how to install and use QuickComment2.

For maximum laziness, here's the entire README.md file from the Github repo copy/pasted.

> ## stackexchange-quickcomment2
>
> This is a tool for Stack Exchange users that allows you to use
>   automatic keyboard-only snippets while typing a comment.
>
> Simply press the hotkey (Alt+X by default), type in the name (or a
>   substring of the name) of the snippet you wish to use (such as
>   "welcome" or "linkonly"), and hit enter.
>
> ### Usage instructions
>
> 1. Install userscript (in Chrome, type `chrome://extensions` in the URL bar and    drag'n'drop the qc2.user.js file into the page)
> 2. Visit a Stack Exchange site and start writing a comment
> 3. Press Alt+X, enjoy
>
> ### Screenshots
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> ### Demo GIFs
>
> My recording program managed to mangle the colors so badly that some
>   of the text isn't even visible. Sorry about that :/
>
> #### Inserting an autocomment
>
> [image]
>
> #### Changing the hotkey
>
> [image]
>
> #### Other settings (editing an autocomment)
>
> [image]
>
> #### Narrowing down via typing substrings
>
> [image]