# Math buttons for sites without MathJax support

Tags: script, editing, mathjax

## Download

[View source](https://gist.github.com/camilstaps/40b62910f0206ef97d50822014870884) or [install](https://unpkg.com/stack-exchange-html-math-editor/HTML_math_editor.user.js) (you will need a plugin like GreaseMonkey for this).

## What it does

For sites that don't have MathJax support, but occasionally need math, HTML codes like `&cap;` and `<sup>..</sup>` are useful. However, less tech-savvy users may not find this as easily. An example of these sites is [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com).

This user script adds a math button to the editor that opens a bar with common mathematical symbols:

[image]

[image]

Note: I just added the symbols that I thought would be used most, having Philosophy.SE in mind - hence the emphasis on logical symbols. If need be, other symbols could be added (leave an answer/comment here or at the source link above). If you have some symbols that you would like to have, but are not sure others would use as much, you can just edit the source for yourself of course.

Comment: I installed the script and have both the Greasemonkey add-on and the userscript itself enabled, but I'm just not shown any button. What am I doing wrong? (The problem is not in Greasemonkey; [a different stack app](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) is working fine.)

Comment: The console in the Firefox inspector tells me `Script error: ReferenceError: "$ is not defined"`. Is this an issue with jQuery?

Comment: @lemontree that's odd, here it was broken as well but with a different error. I have fixed the bug that I can see and updated the install link, could you try reinstalling the script?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction! It works now. I am now shown the button and can use the symbols as desired. The only thing that seems incomplete is that I can't hide the symbols once I opened them (the math button disapperas once I click it). Shouldn't it be possible to close the bar again with a second click on the button?

Comment: @lemontree yes, that would probably be better, but I don't think I have time for that anytime soon myself, unfortunately :(